# Get generated HTML container content length

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get HTML container content length that receives HTML data dynamically. But it is not working, I get the object.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
            var adsense_box_len = $('.container').on('ready', '.adsense-box', function(e) {
                return $(this)[0].length();
            });
            console.log(adsense_box_len);
        });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('.adsense-box').html('This is html dynamic generated');
        });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="adsense-box">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear what your use case is but there is no ready event for elements and only a few elements like `<iframe>` and `<img>` have load events

If you are needing to monitor third party content then use a MutationObserver or an interval timer.

---

If this is for modifying your own content you can create a custom event listener and trigger that when you make modifications

```js
// custom event listener
$('.adsense-box').on('content-changed', function(e) {
  console.log('content-changed, len=', $(this).contents().length)
});

// modify content and trigger custom event
$('.adsense-box').html('This is html dynamic generated').trigger('content-changed');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="adsense-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With Jquery 1.11 what would be the version, can see it's still sending `n.fn.init [div.container, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".container"]`

Comment: That is a jQuery object and you are back to trying to get things from that object incorrectly again